# How to add points for each unclicked button?

Tags: java, android

So, I have 16 buttons, and when user clicks on a button I setText to it from db. He now has guess final answer from these term. I need to add him a point for each button that he did not clicked in his game. I tried:

```
if(!button.isPressed){
points = points + 1;
}
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a global counter and increase it on every button press (onClickListener).
Then deduct the counter from the total number of buttons and that's your score.

Comment: Great idea! Let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize points to 16 and on each button click reduce it by one.

Point left finally would automatically equal to number of buttons not pressed.